# Transforming Attributes to Elements

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes

I've researched for several hours and have found examples that are close but not quite correct.
I have this:

```
<SubjectData id="ID0001156024">
    <Data value="1-00074.jpg" name="Custom1"/>
    <Data value=" Teacher" name="Position"/>
    <Data value="Stacy" name="FirstName"/>
    <Data value="Staff" name="Grade"/>
    <Data value="Moyer" name="LastName"/>
    <Data value="10420681" name="Password"/>
    <Data value="9001" name="StudentID"/>
</SubjectData>
```

I would like to have this:

```
<SubjectData>
    <id>ID0001156024</id>
    <Custom1>1-00074.jpg</Custom1>
    <Position>Teacher</Position>
    <FirstName>Stacy</FirstName>
    <Grade>Staff</Grade>
    <LastName>Moyer</LastName>
    <Password>10420681</Password>
    <StudentID>9001</StudentID>
</SubjectData>
```

I would appreciate any and all help.

Comment: To avoid appearing to be asking for code to be written for you, adapt "close but not quite correct" to fit your needs, post your attempt, and only ask a specific question regarding where you're stuck.

Comment: Thank you for your insight to my question. I will apply it in the future.